# window.print() set window height width in mm when user select page size at run time

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a portal in which user select page size (in mm)and when print preview open then it will be in page size which user have selected.

is this possible to set page size in mm choosen by user at run time through window.open().

[image]

Comment: please add your script to question too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set size in `@page` media before calling `window.print`

```
var css = '@page { size: 50mm 50mm; }',
    head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    style = document.createElement('style');

style.type = 'text/css';
style.media = 'print';

if (style.styleSheet){
  style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}

head.appendChild(style);

window.print();
```

Comment: Can you take a screenshot?

Comment: yes sir, please take a look i have edited question.

Comment: this code is working for A0, A1 but not working for A2 and A3 size. what to do?